# AWS Cloudwatch how to use parse regex for request uri?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I have an AWS Cloudwatch log in the following format

| timestamp | request_uri |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-19 00:00:00 | /v1/categorya/producta?model=112 |
| 2023-04-19 00:00:00 | /v1/categorya/producta?model=11432 |
| 2023-04-19 00:00:00 | /v1/categoryb/productb?model=1145432 |

I want to group by `request_uri` to get the number of calls for a certain endpoint in Cloudwatch so that I can analyze the number of times an endpoint is called during a certain period of time. Currently, I'm using the following query

```
 fields request_uri 
| parse  request_uri "(\/v1\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+)" as uri
| stats count(*) by uri
```

But I think parse is not able to parse request_uri correctly since it shows null for all the values in uri column when I display it. I need help with parsing the correct regex for getting the following results

| uri | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| /v1/categorya/producta | 2 |
| /v1/categoryb/productb | 1 |

When I'm using the following I get null in the created column

```
 fields request_uri 
| parse  request_uri "(\/[a-z]+)" as uri
```

[image]

So it is clear for me that Cloudwatch is not able to parse the regex but not sure what is wrong with the regex or cloudwatch insights query.

Comment: Shouldn't this be @request_uri, missing the @. Also why do you need fields you can just start with parse.

Comment: @furydrive I think @ comes with default fields like timestamp and message not with a custom field that we create.

Comment: Could you try surrounding the regex in angled brackets,

parse  request_uri /(\/v1\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+)/ as uri

disclaimer, not sure if it will work but worth the effort.

Comment: Sorry I meant forward slashes... feel free to delete my comments if not helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CloudWatch requires you to name your capture group when performing parsing with regex.

Also, the expression must be surrounded with forward slashes `/` instead of quotation marks.

A correct parse statement in your case would look like this:

```
parse request_uri /(?<uri>\/v1\/[a-z]+\/[a-z]+)/
```

As you can see, there is no need for `as`, since the field name is derived from the named capture group. This can be used to extract multiple fields using a single regular expression.